# Tarjeta siempre queda del mismo tamaño y no se adapta al tamaño de la imagen en el diseño responsive. html, css

Tags: css, html5, css-grid-layout

El diseño está planteado con grid y no sé si de pronto el problema sea que los valores de width y heigth están asignados estáticamente, es por esto que al momento de realizar el diseño responsive no se adapta al tamaño de la imagen y a esto me refiero a que al pararse en la imagen, por medio del hover la tarjeta debe subir pero al subir se ve mas grande que la imagen o algunas veces mas pequeña dependiendo el dipositivo en el que se prueba.

Ya intenté poner `position: relative` en el selector *producto* pero tampoco me funcionó.

**Código HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
        <div class="producto">
            <div class="glass">
                <h2 class="titulo1">Vue Js</h2>
                <h3 class="titulo2">Camiseta Hombre</h3>
                <p class="tallas">Tallas disponibles</p>
                <div class="contenido">
                    <a href="#" class="talla">S</a>
                    <a href="#" class="talla">M</a>
                    <a href="#" class="talla">L</a>
                    <a href="#" class="talla">XL</a>
                </div>
                <p class="precio">$50.000</p>
            </div>
            <a href="producto.html">
                <div class="imagen__producto">
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="imagen camisa">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**Código CSS**

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    gap: 3rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    }
}
.producto{
    background-color: var(--primarioOscuro);
    padding: 1rem;
}

.glass{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    gap: 5px;    
    width: 293px;
    height: 113px;
    margin-top: 170px;
    position: absolute;

    background-color: rgba(122, 61, 146, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(1px);

    text-align: center;
    transition: 1.5s all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
   
.glass:hover{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 14px;
    height: 282px;
    width: 293px;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(199, 108, 218, 0.4);
    transition: 1.5s all;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "tarjeta ... no se adapta al tamaño de la imagen", es la tarjeta que se tiene que adaptar a la imagen?? o la imagen a la tarjeta?? De todas maneras prueba borrando todo el media query (@media (min-width: 768px) --> toda esta regla) y pone en la clase .grid grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(340px, 100%), 1fr))

Comment: No se adaptaba al tamaño de la imagen... ahora lo que sucede que que al dar en inspeccionar y utilizar varios dispositivos en unos si funciona y en otros no, por ejemplo en iPad Air o Galaxy Fold o iPad Mini, la tarjeta se ve mas grande que la imagen y la distribucion del grid no se hace adecuadamente ya que la primer columna se ve bien pero la otra se ve mucho mas pequeña. muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda